# PHP - Export MySQL tables to JSON file

Tags: php, mysql, json, export

I am trying to export my MySQL tables from my database to a JSON file, so I can list them in an array.

I can create files with this code no problem:

```
        $sql=mysql_query("select * from food_breakfast");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
    $ID=$row['ID'];
    $Consumption=$row['Consumption'];
    $Subline=$row['Subline'];
    $Price=$row['Price'];
    $visible=$row['visible'];

    $posts[] = array('ID'=> $ID, 'Consumption'=> $Consumption, 'Subline'=> $Subline, 'Price'=> $Price, 'visible'=> $visible);
    }
    $response['posts'] = $posts;

    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
    fclose($fp);
```

Now this reads a table and draws it's info from the fields inside it.

I would like to know if it is possible to make a JSON file with the names of the tables, so one level higher in the  hierarchy.

I have part of the code:

```
    $showtablequery = "
    SHOW TABLES
    FROM
        [database]
    LIKE
    '%food_%'
    ";

$sql=mysql_query($showtablequery);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
     {
       $tablename = $row[0];

     $posts[] = array('tablename'=> $tablename);
      }
     $response['posts'] = $posts;
```

But now i am stuck in the last line where is says: `$ID=$row['ID'];` This relates to the info inside the Table and I do not know what to put here.

Also as you can see, I need to filter the Tables to only list the tables starting with food_ and drinks_

Any help is greatly appreciated:-)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'table id' in MySQL and therefore the result set from `SHOW TABLES` has no index `id`. The only index in the resultset is named 'Tables_in_DATABASENAME'.

Also you should use the mysqli library as the good old mysql library is depreacted. Having prepared an example:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli(
    'yourserver',
    'yourusername',
    'yourpassword',
    'yourdatabasename'
);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") "
         . $mysqli->connect_error;
}


$result = $mysqli->query('SHOW TABLES FROM `yourdatabasename` LIKE \'%food_%\'');
if(!$result) {
    die('Database error: ' . $mysqli->error);
}

$posts = array();
// use fetch_array instead of fetch_assoc as the column
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $tablename = $row[0];
    $posts []= array (
        'tablename' => $tablename
    );
}

var_dump($posts);
```

Comment: ok, so I got that and it generates the file, but does not populate the array - I have updated the code to get the formatting right, please see the second section.

Comment: No not yet, sorry for the delay -> is the secret, the pw to the database and the test the name of the database?

Comment: so how does it know what the user and secret are??

Comment: yeah I thought so, what i mean is, do I replace them, or do I define them before hand, so that the code knows where to look?? I use  mysql_connect("localhost", "username",  "password"); to define them

Comment: just replace them in `new mysqli( ...)`

Comment: Alright, that seems to work, but my MySQL database is not localhost, it is a server address, so I can't fully test it, as it is saying that I am using an Unknown MySQL server host - but I am not.

Comment: can you ping the host from the commandline of your php machine? it is a hostname or an IP?

Comment: well I know it works, because my website is live and running from it, but will do

Comment: weird the ping returns the same answer, but the website is running from it - i'll try an work it out.

Comment: This query also works: `USE information_schema; SELECT \`table_name\` FROM \`tables\` WHERE \`table_schema\` = 'test' AND \`table_name\` LIKE '%food%';`

Comment: OK the array is printed to the screen, but no table content

Comment: Ok got it working:-) Thanks for the patience and helping me with the new connection method, hence the +1

Comment: Yeah I did that, so that is how I came about the server error.